# Karnaugh Map and Seven Segment Display Question

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am honestly confused over here. I understand how bit manipulation works. But when it comes to Boolean Algebra I seem to be a bit stumped.

So if A = 1, then ~A = 0.

But in this example (~A * ~B) + (~C * ~D) = 0 + 0 or 0 | 0 = 0. But in this example it equals 1.
[Karnaugh Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWAP9.png)

[Seven Segment Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izntd.png)

Comment: If $A=1$, then $\sim A = 0$, sure.  But also, if $A=0$, then $\sim A=1$.  The $1$ in the K-map says that when all four inputs are false, you want the e segment to lit up.  By the way, that box of the K-map corresponds to $\sim A * \sim B * \sim C * \sim D$, which is true when all four inputs are false.

Comment: Ah I was thinking that might be that case because in programming if you do if (A && B && C && D) which means its a true statement. I get it now, I was a bit confused on why the ~ was in there I thought A was 1 by default. But it turns out those are the cases to get the output segment of e.

Comment: How do I upvote you and close this?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A=1$, then $\sim\! A=0$, sure. But also, if $A=0$, then $\sim\! A=1$. The $1$ in the K-map says that when all four inputs are false, you want the e segment of the display to lit up.

By the way, that box of the K-map corresponds to the *minterm*

$$ \sim\! A \,∗ \sim\! B\, ∗ \sim\! C\, ∗ \sim\! D \enspace,$$

which is true when all four inputs are false.